# Recreating Layers based on data already entered

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, query

**Background:**
Construction events take place on a certain block of road. The events are based on data like Lane#, Layer#, and SP and EP (Start Position and End Position).

I created a picture to make it easier to visualize
[image]

Now there are two things you can do to a specific layer in a lane:

1. Get rid of some material
2. Add some material

The entire layer for a lane is not made in one day, so on day 1 they could put together layer 4 from SP=0 to EP=75 and so on and so forth.

**Data:**

The data that I have looks like this:

```
Lane#|Activity|Date       |Layer#|SP |EP |Start_Thick|End_Thick  
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |1     |0  |150|0          |0  
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |2     |0  |150|12         |12  
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |3     |0  |150|10.5       |10.5   
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |4     |0  |150|2          |2  
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |5     |0  |100|2          |2  
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |5     |100|150|2          |3  
1    |Sub     |10/20/2000 |5     |0  |125|-1         |-1  
1    |Sub     |10/20/2000 |5     |125|150|-1         |-1.5  
1    |Add     |10/20/2000 |6     |0  |50 |2          |2  
1    |Add     |10/20/2000 |6     |50 |150|2          |2
```

**Result:**
The result I want to get when I say get me a snapshot for Lane 1 at SP>=0 and EP<=150 is this:

```
Lane#|Layer#|SP |EP |Start_Thick|End_Thick  
1    |1     |0  |150|0          |0  
1    |2     |0  |150|12         |12  
1    |3     |0  |150|10.5       |10.5   
1    |4     |0  |150|2          |2  
1    |5     |0  |100|1          |1  <<
1    |5     |100|125|1          |1.5  <<
1    |5     |125|150|1.5        |1.5    <<   
1    |6     |0  |50 |2          |2  
1    |6     |50 |150|2          |2
```

Layer 5 can be explained like this:
[image]

The first two entries in the original table shows the addition of materials and the latter two shows removal from different positions. I have not tried to interpolate before with SQL so I am not sure if this is possible or not but I would appreciate any help.

I might have missed some information so feel free to ask for additional details if needed.

I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Interesting question. Can you update your question with the SQL you have so far and a description of what’s wrong with it? Please also include DDL